# React JS 'propTypes' validators running twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

The code below creates ordered and un-ordered list. Although other parts of code is not posted here because of irrelevance

Question:
I'm passing some properties to 'List' component by invoking it in 'Navigation' component. I'm validating the items received by 'List' by running some validations via propTypes of 'List'. However, I noticed that validations are running twice. I couldn't figure out why?

Is it because of some race conditions happening inside the code. Or, is it a bug in React?

```
var Navigation = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         <nav>
            <List type="ol" items={this.props.items} />
         </nav>
      );
   }
});
var List = React.createClass({
   propTypes: {
      type: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      items: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
        if (props["type"] !== "ol" && props["type"] !== "ul") {
           return new Error("Incorrect list type provided");
        }
      }
   },
   getInitialState: function() {
      return {
         showList: true,
         listType: this.props.type
      }
   },
   render: function() {
      return (
         <this.state.listType>
            {this.props.items.map(function(item) {
               return <ListItem data={item} />
            })}
         </this.state.listType>
      )
   }
});

React.render(<Navigation items={items} />, document.body);
```

Comment: How do you know they are running twice?  What output do you see?

Comment: @DavinTryon I set a breakpoint in 'customProp' and traversed back in the call stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of React's introduction of descriptors in 0.11
This issue is still present in v0.12. The links below talk more about this.

[React Github issue on this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1910)

[React v0.11 blog on propValidation](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#prop-type-validation)

Answer (score 1):

Your customProp refers to and check another prop: 'type'. If you need a custom function, put that after the prop you want to apply the function to.

You actually need only 2 propTypes: type and items. You want to ensure that the type provided is either 'ol' or 'ul'.
To do this you do not need a 3rd propType.

Change the propTypes code to:

```
propTypes: {
  type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['ol', 'ul']),
  items: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
},
```

Then you do not need your customProp. And then your code should do what you want.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, it works and thanks. But that doesn't answer my question. customProps shouldn't be doing two rounds for validation. I found couple of articles related to it.